# Little boy killed too early, isekais to a younger body, gains wolf companion and a noble adoption

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a manga where a little boy is killed too early. As an apology god transports him to another world in a younger body and gives him a big wolf I think black as protection. A noble finds him that is also a knight and adopts him and they camp out for a few days till the paperwork is settled. Then they go through the knight's entrance instead of the normal one. Then he meats the nobles family. then after time the kid saves a creature that people are trying to get and when the kid. Then when he goes to bed a wakes up the next morning a maid get concerned and brakes his room and makes him cry and then apologies bye the end of the night the room is fixed and when the creature and boy go out they wear matching bear onesies. Fantasy setting

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: From what I remember black and white

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the boy's name? How did he die? What kind of noble adopted him? What colour was the wolf? What is a "knight's entres"? What kind of onesies were they wearing? What kind of god was it? What is the setting (e.g. fantasy/medieval)? Was there any adult content (sex/nudity/gore) or was it for more general audiences?

Comment: I edited it a bit

Comment: Can you elaborate on the maid breaking the room? Was this an accident or was the maid bullying him? Also, if the creature was wearing a bear onesie, does that mean it was humanoid?

Comment: It's was a accident that destroyed the room and it was a creature that was a in a onesie like in pajamas like a costume

Comment: Does this story have the protagonist meet god in the first chapter, and immediately gets the wolf? Or does he reincarnate first and meet god after the fact and get an explanation then?

Comment: Die, meet god, reincarnate, get wolf

Comment: I found it it's called yasashii kazoku to, takusan no mofumofu ni kakomarete @qazmlpok

Comment: Could you post that as a self-answer and include a description of the manga plot points that match and a link to an aggregator website, e.g. my anime list? That will make it clear to others that the question has been answered, and may help future people looking for the same manga.

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: The answer box is directly below the comments section. There are other examples on the site of the content and level of detail for story-identification answers. If you prefer, I can just write it myself, but you won't get any credit for that.

Answer (score 2):

[*Yasashii Kazoku to, Takusan no Mofumofu ni Kakomarete*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/yasashii-kazoku-to-takusan-no-mofumofu-ni-kakomarete-light-novel)

> A different world that Yuki and his friends develop! Elementary school student Yuki Takahashi died one day from an unfortunate incident. "The dog is waiting for you over there." Yuki, who reincarnated in a different world with the fluffy dog (Fenrir), decided to live at the the house of a caption knight. Yuki meets a lot of fluffy and kind people. Happy life in a different world begins now!

Comment: You can click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept it, as per the [tour].